# What is the serious version of "dabble"?

Tags: antonyms

**[At Merriam Webster, the word *dabble* is defined as follows:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dabble)**

*to work without any deep involvement*, or *to take part in an activity in a way that is not serious*, as in

> I just dabble in art.

I'm writing a blog post about the general process of mastering skills in life. Two of the steps are: **1)** observation of the skill to learn its finer details, and **2)** repetition by copying seniors in the field in order to get said details burned into the nervous system.

I first thought of calling these two steps combined as *"the dabble phase"*. In other words, you "dabble" around as you learn the ins and outs of your chosen skill.

According to the definition above, however, *dabble* does not encompass this meaning very well. What I need is a word or phrase that describes a slow but serious effort to learn.

More simply, I need a word which means *to take part in an activity in way that is systematic and serious*. In other words, I need a definition which is really the opposite of the definition for *dabble*.

Comment: Most people call that "trying."  *As in:* Did you *try* to do it?  No, not really.  I just dabbled around a bit.

Comment: Yes, and thesaurus.com says its antonym is "take seriously", but I hoped for a more inspiring word or phrase to describe the process. I mean, "The trying phase" or "The Take-it-seriously phase" isn't too memorable.

Comment: The probation phase.  The attempt phase.  The trying it phase.  The experimentation phase.  The exploration phase.  The not-dabbling-but-really-giving-it-a-chance phase.  The good-ol'-college-try phase.  The I'm-really-serious-about-getting-this-to-work phase.

Comment: I would say "labor" or some such.  "He labored on the development of the device."

Comment: Labor or exploration sounds good. I'll try looking for words like this and see if I find one even more fitting. If not, i'll go with one of these

Comment: @MartinH : The pilot phase.  Where I work, when something is in the final phases and we have a working model, the undertaking of the first real attempt at implementation is called a *pilot.*  That phase is called the *pilot phase.*

Comment: _Drill_ or _practice_.

Comment: See [*dabbling duck*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dabbling_duck) and [*diving duck*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diving_duck). The first stays on the surface and just reaches down a bit. The second goes all in, in an in-depth hunt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To take part in an activity in way that is systematic and serious**

You could call such a phase the "[**immersion**](https://www.google.co.kr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=immersion+definition) **phase**."

> Google definition
>
> noun
>
> 1. the action of immersing someone or something in a liquid.
> 2. deep mental involvement.

See also, [**immerse**](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=immerse+definition&oq=immerse+d&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.5791j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

> Google definition
>
> verb
>
> involve oneself deeply in a particular activity or interest.

The word suggests a deep involvement in the activity and a deep mental focus for the activity.

It is commonly used to describe a method of teaching foreign languages to students where the students are constantly exposed to the language they are learning.

[Here](https://medschool.vanderbilt.edu/ume/IP) is the use of the word to describe a med-school course at Vanderbilt university:

> During a portion of the **immersion phase**, students will participate in a three- to six-month mentored research experience, tailored around each student’s particular research and clinical interests. The longitudinal curricular elements of Foundations of Health Care Delivery and Learning Communities will remain integral to student development during the Immersion Phase.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Memorable and descriptive. Thank you very much :)